# Permalinks pointing to HTTP even after inserting Certificate

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, https

My site was of HTTP Version and recently installed certificate. Currently it is pointing to HTTPS URL but permalinks still pointing to HTTP version of the URL. Under WordPress Settings -> General ->WordPress Address URL and Site Address URL are still pointing to HTTP version but are greyed down and I can't even edit.

How can I ensure all the permalinks are pointed to HTTPS version?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Hm, go to settings and check are the links HTTPS or HTTP. If they are HTTPS then try Really simple SSL plugin and that shoud work.